# Can Quickblox provide Javascript-based video chat on iOS?

Tags: ios, webrtc, quickblox, videochat

I can't use an app on iOS, it has to be in-the-browser javascript, and it has to be video chat.
Can I support this on quickblox? I know that webRTC is not currently available on iOS. 
I am sure this used to be a supported case before the move to webRTC?
Does the deprecated API offer this? Do we know when we can expect webRTC to be supported in the browser on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC javascript API should work on iOS Opera/Chrome browsers, but not in Safari unfortunately

Comment: The following comment on quickblox website led me to understand that this was not the case:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web

Unfortunately, these features are unsupported in IE and Safari, and iOS mobile browsers.

It's certainly not working for me on iOS at the moment in any iOS browser...